# Interface with default key value types that can be extended TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, generics, types, static-typing

In many of my projects, I have a common pattern which repeats over and over again.

```
type RequestStatus =
  | 'pending'
  | 'requesting'
  | 'successful'
  | 'failed'

type AValue = string | undefined

type OtherValue = number

interface State {
  requestStatus: RequestStatus;
  aValue?: AValue;
  otherValue?: OtherValue;
}

const [requestState, setRequestState] = useState<State>({
  requestStatus: 'pending',
  aValue: 'aValue',
  otherValue: 11
});

const appendToState = (state: Partial<State>) =>
  setRequestState(previousState => ({ ...previousState, ...state }));
```

In such a scenario, I am fetching values and changing the UI based on the `requestStatus` and the values.

This repeats over and over again in my projects and in an attempt to reduce the repetitions, I am considering wrapping all this in a hook. My main problem is dealing with types.

This was one of my attempts.

```
export const useExtendedRequestStatus = <T>(state: T) => {
  const [requestState, setRequestState] = useState<{ requestStatus: RequestStatus } & T>({
    requestStatus: 'pending',
    ...state,
  });

  const appendToState = (state: Partial<T>) =>
    setRequestState(previousState => ({ ...previousState, ...state }));

  return { requestState, setRequestState, appendToState };
};
```

And i would implement it like this

```
const {
  requestStatus,
  appendToState
} = useExtendedRequestStatus<{ requestStatus: RequestStatus; aValue: AValue }>({
  aValue: aValue,
  requestStatus: 'successful',
});
```

It works but not perfectly. There are instances if I am statically type checking the hook, I have to re-define the `RequestStatus` type which is already defined in the hook. I am wondering if there is a way, `RequestStatus` will still be in the hook when manually type checking without having to re-define it.

I am open to any ideas.

Comment: Do you mean that when you use it as `useExtendedRequestStatus<{ requestStatus: RequestStatus; aValue: AValue }>({...})`, you would like to avoid having to mention the `requestStatus: RequestStatus;` part, but still be able to call it with an argument that contains a `requestStatus` member?

Comment: Yes, if its possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You indeed use a `T` generic in your `useExtendedRequestStatus` custom hook, which describes the possible members of the state you want to use it with.

But since you specify that the `state` argument, when you call your custom hook, is of type `T` directly, if you want it to include an initial `requestStatus`, then you are forced to also mention this `requestStatus` member in your explicit concrete type (of course you could rely on automatic type inference, but I guess you have your reasons to manually type check).

You can easily "embed" this predefined member in your custom hook, and have it available for your argument (same for `appendToState`), in a very similar manner you have already done with your inner `useState<{ requestStatus: RequestStatus } & T>({...})`: simply specify that your `state` argument is also of type `T & { requestStatus: RequestStatus }` (or maybe even better `T & Partial<{ requestStatus: RequestStatus }>` in case `requestStatus` can be initially omitted, as suggested by your initial default value in your custom hook). That way, `T` no longer needs to contain the `requestStatus` member. Same for `appendToState`.

```
interface IRequestStatus {
  requestStatus: RequestStatus;
}

export const useExtendedRequestStatus = <T>(
  state: T & Partial<IRequestStatus> // Initial state can contain requestStatus, even if not mentioned in concrete T
) => {
  const [requestState, setRequestState] = useState<IRequestStatus & T>({
    requestStatus: 'pending',
    ...state,
  });

  const appendToState = (state: Partial<T & IRequestStatus>) =>
    setRequestState((previousState) => ({ ...previousState, ...state }));

  return { requestState, setRequestState, appendToState };
};
```

Now in your React functional component, you can use it like this:

```
const { requestState, appendToState } = useExtendedRequestStatus<{
  //requestStatus: RequestStatus; // Can now be omitted
  aValue: AValue;
}>({
  aValue: aValue,
  requestStatus: 'successful', // Okay
});

requestState.requestStatus; // Okay

appendToState({
  requestStatus: 'successful', // Okay
});
```

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-eyyzhg?file=Hello.tsx